# How to add a stylesheet into a WinForm WebBrowser in C#?

Tags: c#, css, webbrowser-control, stylesheet

I am wanting to manipulate a page being loaded in a WebBrowser by adding a stylesheet on the DocumentComplete event.  I'd like to do it without using an external file, if possible.

Most of the solutions I've seen involve deprecated methods or libraries such as mshtml.  The MSDN says that the accepted method is to use **HtmlElement myelement = mywebbrowser.Document.CreateElement(
"style")**, but nothing else.  Manipulation of such seems to be problematic - things like trying to set InnerHtml throws an error at runtime (ie, *System.NotSupportedException: Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement*).

Given all that, what is the best/proper way to add a big chunk of CSS to a page loaded in a WebBrowser?

Comment: Using document.CreateElement() is probably the best and cleanest way. Another way would be adding some large script block to edit the elements in question's CSS properties. Thie drawbacks of this method are of obvious.  The other, less recommended way would be editing the document text directly through webbrowser.documenttext  property.   This causes a navigation to about:blank first and could be undesirable depending on what you are doing.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have to ask though, why do you need to load more CSS after the page has already loaded? The only scenario where that makes sense is if you don't own the page that is being loaded.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: thanks for the advice, but as I mentioned createelement throws an error when I try to add the css using the innerhtml method and I am not seeing any other good way to add a large chunk of CSS at once. Editing items element by element is not feasible in this case.  And we do own the page, it's in salesforce, but it's not loading the CSS properly due to some kind of JS madness that is failing and I need to get something out the door ASAP as a quick fix to give me time to fix whatever the actual issue is.